# Incorrect date formating in Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, com

I'm working on a Excel AddIn, that include an Excel workbook as template.

In all the worksheets of this workbook, the date is correctly formatted (I mean, I type 01/01/2013, and it displays 01/01/2013). But in only **one worksheet of the workbook**, the date isn't displayed correctly. I type **01/01/2013**, and it displays **41275**. And when I select this cell, the cell still displays 41275, but the formula area displays the correct date, i-e 01/01/2013.

Some precisions:

- Using Excel 2010, 32bits, in English (I know sometimes locale might influence the formula).
- The formating of the cells is the same (right click -> Format cells ... is type of Date for all the cells, in all the worksheets).
- I'm doing some modifications with this AddIn, using C# and the Component Object Model, but the modifications are the same for the entire Workbook (nothing specific to a worksheet).

Any ideas/clues where it could come from ? And how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Excel stores dates as excel serial dates. This is normal behavior.

Comment: Since it happens only in one worksheet, I don't think this is Excel normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this snippit to convert from excel serial date format

```
    protected static DateTime FromExcelSerialDate(int serialDate)
    {
        if (serialDate > 59) serialDate -= 1; //Excel/Lotus 2/29/1900 bug   
        return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(serialDate);
     }
```

Comment: I was hopping for a way to solve this incorrect formating in my Excel workbook template, before any C# modification, because the problem appears there. I don't have problem when using the date, but when displaying it.